# Minimal BASH-like when trying to boot from a live USB

Tags: grub2, live-usb

I deleted all partitions from my notebook through gparted to reinstall the xubuntu and now I can't load a live USB to reinstall it. I'm seeing this `Minimal BASH-like` error and the `grub>` prompt and going to **EFI Shell** screen if I run `exit` on this grub prompt.

`ls` returns `(memdisk) (hd0) (hd1) (hd2) (hd3)`

Anyone knows how to boot my live USB from grub or even EFI Shell prompt to create my linux partitions and perform the reinstallation?

My notebook is a Positivo Motion q232a and I created the live USB using **Unetbootin** and Xubuntu **18.04**.

Comment: Just to be clear: I delete all partitions because I was locked on EFI Shell and any encountered solutions worked for me. So I was going to try to reinstall it :/

Comment: Please tell us about your computer: brand name and model. Tell us also how you created your USB live drive: Which version did you download? Did you check the downloaded iso file with md5sum?  Which tool did you use to make the USB drive bootable with Xubuntu? Have you tried to boot from the USB drive in some other computer?

Comment: @sudodus unfortunately I didn't tested the iso file using md5sum or another computer. Additional informations required were added on the question description.

Comment: It is a good idea to make sure that the USB boot drive is good (test in another computer). Then you can try to make your computer boot from it. Maybe [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick) can help.

Comment: @sudosus yeah. I'll test it tomorrow to make sure all is good.